# SNV Tortoise Checkout or browser repo error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to connect to the Repository to checkout the project(s), but I get the following errors:

> Unable to connect to repository at URL
>
> 'http://....'
>
> Access to 'svn/....' forbidden

**Please note the following:**

- I have tested my user on a different PC, it worked
- I have tried to login with a different user on my PC, I got the same
  error
- I have downloaded different version of SVN, previously 1.8, now 1.9,
  but with  same error
- I am able to see the Folders of the repository, but no files are
  shown!
- All the topics I red was not helpful, I've spent two days reading
  about this, its all rotating about User Privileges, firewalls
  settings... which I rolled out by my troubleshooting
- All troubleshooting I did leads to the fact that there is something
  wrong with my PC/PC Network settings!
- My PC is in a domain environment; all other PC are supposed to have
  the same settings
- My PC user is a local PC admin
- I had an issue with Proxy Settings, the exceptions were added and its
  not making an issue anymore
- Opening the Repository URL in browser works normally; I use my
  username and password for accessing the Repository without any
  issues.

**UPDATE**

- I have formatted my PC and upgraded to windows 10, but still I am getting the same error, So obviously, this is not PC related issue[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYoLy.png)

**My question is**, how to triangulate the issue?! where to look, is there any specified logs to show where exactly it couldn't continue?

Answer (score -1):

You don't have permissions to the URL that you want to access. That is why you get "Access Forbidden" error. Contact an administrator or your manager for assistance with this.

Comment: As I said, I can access the URL without issues using the web-browser from the PC that is not able to connect through the SVN client

Comment: @simsim you did not show the urls, so this information is useless.

Comment: can you explain how would URLs will help you in this case? I don't think it is relevant!

Comment: @simsim access rules and paths in SVN are case-sensitive. A typo can cause such behavior.

Comment: It appeared that our network admin had it as a warning on his screen, not as a blockage, but the connection was being blocked either way from his side (firewall auto action).  so after a fresh windows install, all fingers was pointing to the firewall between me and the SVN server, and then he (the network admin) admitted that it is from his side!, nothing wrong with my URL though, as I said before earlier, the same URL works from the browser, copy and paste, no room for error there.   Problem is solved now after all this struggle by idiot network admin who didn't take this seriously before